# How to remove react router location state for previous location after navigating to another page using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to remove the location state after navigating to other page.

Suppose I am in page1. I render some state using `useEffect`.

```
const Page1 = () => {
   const location = useLocation();
   useEffect(() => {
      const location_state = location.state;
      if ((location_state !== undefined) {
         // pass the state value to local state
      }
   })
}
```

Now if move to the any next page then how to remove the location state of page1?
I used `history.replace()` in the return function of `useEffect` but it does not work.

Comment: why do you need to replace location state though?

Comment: @PrateekThapa I want to restrict it to access from browser navigation

Comment: So, why are you keeping in the location in the first place?

Comment: How do I pass the info from react router link without props from one page to other?

Comment: place in a cookie with expiry date, or put it in localStorage. Access it from the next page.

Comment: It does not matter when user refreshes the page. If user refreshes the page then the data  will keep in the state like that no problem. But I want to navigate to that page from one place thats why I want to remove the state when that page unmount.

Comment: Place it in the cookie with a expiry date or localStorage. Access the data in the next page. In that way, the user won't possibly see the data in the URL.